# Synchronize two OCR engine results

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have two OCR engines. One of these is faster but the other has the better recognition(Abbyy).
So what I am doing is to start two OCRWorker which run on new seperate Thread. After they are finished the raise an Event. I get the results from both engines in my HandlerMethod, but I want them somehow to synchronize and take the better result.
Furthermore I would like to know if this way to start to paralell tasks is a good way and if don't run into possible deadlocks.
Here is my Code:
This Part start the OcrEngineThreads

```
private void OnAreaSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var bmp = (Bitmap)SnippingTool.Image;
  _runningOcrTasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (var engine in _ocrTextRecognizer)
  {
    var ocrWorker = new OcrWorker(bmp, engine);
    ocrWorker.ocrFinishedEvent += OnOcrWorkerFinished;
    ocrWorker.Run();
  }
}

// Both Threads run into this Method
private void OnOcrWorkerFinished(object sender, OcrFinishedEventArgs args)
{
  // I pass this point two times und would like 
  // to protect it from Deadlock and synchronize the result.
  var result = args.Result;
}
```

```
  class OcrWorker
  {
    private Thread t;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private IOcrTextRecognition _ocrEngine;
    public event OcrRecognitionFinishedEvent ocrFinishedEvent;


    public OcrWorker(Bitmap bmp, IOcrTextRecognition ocrEngine)
    {
      this._ocrEngine = ocrEngine;
      this.bmp = bmp;
      this.t = new Thread(StartRecognizeText);
    }

    private void StartRecognizeText()
    {
      string result = this._ocrEngine.ScanImageForText(this.bmp);
      OcrFinishedEventArgs finishedEventArgs = new OcrFinishedEventArgs(true, result);
      if (ocrFinishedEvent != null)
      {
        ocrFinishedEvent.Invoke(this, finishedEventArgs);
      }
      t = null;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
      this.t.Start();
      if (!t.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))) {
#if (!DEBUG)
        t.Abort();
        throw new TimeoutException("OCR recognition took too long");
#endif
      }
    }
  }

  public delegate void OcrRecognitionFinishedEvent(object sender,  OcrFinishedEventArgs args);

  public class OcrFinishedEventArgs
  {
    public bool Success { get; }
    public string Result { get; }

    public OcrFinishedEventArgs(bool success, string result)
    {
      Success = success;
      Result = result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: OcrWorker.Run() doesn't return until it's finished, so nothing is happening in parallel here.  But anyway, if you're going to wait for both of them to finish, then why don't you just run the better one?

Comment: Because the better Engine takes 10 x longer (It use Com Interface). How could I make it run paralell ?? My Aim is first to show a result, but then improve if possible and reshow the result.